# How to get .xinitrc (xinit, startx) to see environment variables

Tags: xorg, environment-variables

How do I get `xinit` to see environment variables?

Given the following `xinitrc`:

`echo test $HOSTNAME test`

I see the output `test test` on the terminal, which indicates `$HOSTNAME` is not set when xinit runs, even though `echo $HOSTNAME` on the terminal (that runs `startx`), it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$HOSTNAME is not an environment variable until you `export` it. Until then, it is only an internal "shell variable" only known to this one process you're typing the commands into. (There are a few other built-in shell variables like this, and any custom variables *you* set also behave this way.)

Your tests using `echo` do not reveal the difference because all variables are expanded by the shell itself, not by the 'echo' command.

Instead, use `env` or `printenv` to see the actual environment block that's inherited by child processes. (Alternatively you could use `declare -p HOSTNAME` to check whether it has the 'x' (export) flag.)

---

Note that the presence of $HOSTNAME doesn't actually depend on whether you're trying to use it interactively or through a script ‐ it appears depending on *which shell* is being used; for example Bash provides it but Sh or Dash do not.

So if your xinitrc script had the `#!/bin/bash` header, it would be able to use $HOSTNAME even if it wasn't inherited through environment.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer, it's really useful! I knew there was a difference between un/exported variables, but I had no idea that the shell created some of them by default, or how to check it. I also didn't know `xinitrc` can be any executable. Great stuff!